# Excel vba find text in sheet, copy range, paste to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am rather new to excel macros and can't figure out how to fix what I need. Basically i'm writing a code that finds text in a sheet, which is currently at B63 ("Today"), selects the row from the found value down to the next value that it should stop at, B83 ("Tomorrow") in this case. The problem is that "Today" and "Tomorrow" tend to move up and down each time I download the new data.

I've tried writing the code for this but haven't had any success and at this point i'm not even sure that I'm taking the right approach. Here is what I have, any help would be appreciated:

Dim Cell As Range

```
    For i = 1 To 100
    For f = 30 To 100
    Sheets("Download").Select
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = "Today" Then
    If Cells(f, "B").Value = "Tomorrow" Then
    'Insert code to select rows from "i" to "f"-1 (one above f)
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Statements").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub test()
Dim td As Range, tm As Range
With Sheets("Download")
    Set td = .[B:B].Find("today")
    Set tm = .[B:B].Find("tomorrow")
    If (Not td Is Nothing) And (Not tm Is Nothing) Then
        .Rows(td.Row & ":" & tm.Offset(-1, 0).Row).Copy Sheets("Statements").[A1]
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

try this

```
Sub test()
Dim td&, tm&, n&, cl As Range, Dwnld As Worksheet, Stmnt As Worksheet
td = 0: tm = 0
Set Dwnld = Sheets("Download"): Set Stmnt = Sheets("Statements")
    With Dwnld
    n = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cl In .Range("B1:B" & n)
        If LCase(cl.Value) = "today" Then td = cl.Row
        If LCase(cl.Value) = "tomorrow" Then tm = cl.Offset(-1, 0).Row
        If td > 0 And tm > 0 Then
            .Rows(td & ":" & tm).Copy Stmnt.Range("A" & Stmnt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            td = 0: tm = 0
        End If
    Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

source

[image]

destination

[image]

Comment: Tried it and it wouldn't do anything. I should also note that "today" and "tomorrow" appear again further down on the same column (B), which is why I had tried to limit the search range with my initial code (if you can call it that) to not search for "tomorrow" past B100. Just to check though, I deleted the other today's and tomorrows from my sheet and it still didn't do anything unfortunately. Thanks for the help so far though!

Comment: if in column `B` values `today` and `tomorrow` are not exist then range will not be copied

Comment: I have tried it on a new sheet and it works great. Not sure why it didn't work on my original sheet, but i'm sure I can figure it out. Is there any way to add a search range to it so that I can set it to search for the next pairs of today and tomorrows?

Comment: yes, but it will be another variant, i will show you in updates

Comment: yep, the first today and tomorrow work beautifully. However, if you add another today and tomorrow in the same column of the download sheet it will pull the whole thing up to one cell above the last tomorrow :/

Comment: would it be possible to simply modify your answer to 'Set td = .[B1:B10].Find("today")' and 'Set td = .[B1:B10].Find("tomorrow")' so that it does not search past those rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79379/discussion-between-reece-and-vasily).