# Loop to find 2 strings and copy to a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find

I am really new to VBA and I am experimenting, but got stuck.

I have a sheet called Full History File with various data in column A.

I then wrote code to create various sheets called Blasted 1 to Blasted i

I now want to use code start in cell A1 on Sheet Full History File to find the string 1 "BLAST DRIVER ON" and then the string 2 "BLAST DRIVER ON" and copy all rows between the string 1 and string 2 - 1 row to sheet Blasted 1

Then it must loop copying the data between String 2 and the next "BLAST DRIVER ON" to sheet Blasted 1 + i

This must continue until a blank cell is reached.

I managed to get the code working to copy the first find, but have no idea how to loop it:

```
Sub CopyData() 
Dim s As Range, e As Range, i As Long 
i = 1 With Sheets("Full History File") 
Set r = .Range("A:A").Find("BLAST DRIVER ON") 
If Not r Is Nothing Then 
Set e = .Range("A:A").Find("BLAST DRIVER ON", r) 
If Not e Is Nothing Then 
.Range(r, e).EntireRow.Cut Sheets("Blasted 1").Range("A1")
End If 
End If 
End With 
End Sub
```

Any and all help please!

If needed here is the code I used to create the sheets that I found using Google:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim b As String
Dim e As String
Dim s As Integer
Sheets("Blast List").Select
b = "A2" 

e = Range(b).End(xlDown).Address 

For Each cell In Range(b, e)
s = Sheets.Count
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(s)
Sheets(s + 1).Name = cell.Value
Next cell
```

Thank you for any and all help

> Revision as I think I explained what I need incorrectly:
>
> What I have in Column A of sheet "FULL HISTORY FILE" is multiple rows that >contains the text "BLAST DRIVER ON" with some other text. I am looking for code >to find the first row (Find 1) and the next row (Find 2) that contains this >text.
>
> I then want the code to create a sheet called Blasted 1 (as it is the first >instance of the found text) and copy all rows between Find 1 and Find 2 to the >newly created sheet "Blasted 1"
>
> I then want the code to find the next row after Find 2 containing the text
> (Find 3) and create a sheet called "Blasted 2" (second instance found) and copy >the rows between Find 2 and Find 3 to the newly created sheet.
>
> I hope this is better understood

Comment: If you want to perform a loop where the number of loops depend on a variable (such as the first empty cell), you can use a do-loop in vba: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586423/excel-vba-find-text-in-sheet-copy-range-paste-to-other-sheet) This is exactly same problem, with accepted answear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will help. You can use a For-Next loop, as I have here, or a Do loop as suggested by Alex.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long, rFind As Range, rFind2 As Range, rFind3 As Range, ws As Worksheet, s As String

s = "BLAST DRIVER ON" 'define search term here so only need to change once if needed

With Sheets("Full History File").Columns(1)
    Set rFind3 = .Find(What:="END HISTORY FILE", LOokat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set rFind = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1)
    For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & s & "*")         'cycle through number of times text is found
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=s, After:=rFind, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          LOokat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 'specify all parameters to be on the safe side
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            Set rFind2 = .Find(What:=s, After:=rFind)                     'find next instance
            Set ws = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))          'add new sheet
            ws.Name = "Blasted " & i                                      'name it
            If i = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "*" & s & "*") Then
                Set rFind2 = rFind3.Offset(1)                             'remove .Offset(1) if you don't want "END OF HISTORY FILE" copied
            End If
            Range(rFind, rFind2.Offset(-1)).Copy ws.Range("A1") 'copy intermediate range
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, Thank you for the assist, but the code you gave me does no action. The sheets aren't created and the information is not copied from FULL HISTORY FILE to the newly created sheet.

Comment: Works for me. Probably the issue is that the text is not found. Perhaps you need `Lookat:=xlpart` - hard to say without knowing your set up.

Comment: Hi SJR, The moment I remove the For i statement and Next i, the code copies to one Sheet "Blasted 0". I debugged the code and noticed it goes to the For i = 1 statement and then immediately goes to End With. Do you perhaps know why?

Comment: As alluded to above, it sounds as if your cells do not contain exactly that text and nothing else. I've made a couple of amendments so give it another try.

Comment: Hi SJR, I found another snag, it does copy the data as I want except for the last event that doesn't get copied onto a sheet. For example...there are 24 times I find "BLAST DRIVER ON" in the sheet, but it only copies until the 23rd event. Another question is how would I also copy the first found with the rest of the data? Thank you again for putting me in the right direction

Comment: Is there data after the last ""BLAST DRIVER ON" that should be copied? I assumed the last cell contained that text.

Comment: Yes the last cell after the last BLAST DRIVER ON will END OF HISTORY FILE. I modified the code to include the first found event. So that is fixed.

Comment: So after the last instance of BLAST DRIVER ON there are some cells with data and then a cell containing END OF HISTORY FILE every time?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but this is a much simpler version of the loop you've described. It negates the need to find a specific value in a range of cells, and the range between two hits.

```
Sub BLAST()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim last As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, cel As Range
last = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
i = 0
j = 2
For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & last)
    If cel.Value = "BLAST" Then
        i = i + 1
        j = 2
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Blasted " & i
        Sheets("Blasted " & i).Range("A1") = cel.Value
    Else
        Sheets("Blasted " & i).Range("A" & j) = cel.Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next cel
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This simply loops through all the cells in your range, and if the criteria is found, the cell value is copied to a new sheet with the name "Blasted " + the next number. Then every subsequent cell is copied into the next row on that sheet, until another match is found.

It's a bit basic at the moment but can easily be modified to suit your needs (copy entire row instead of value for example, or end at next blank cell instead of the full used range in A:A)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example with a slightly different approach. It sets up the range for your source data and just walks straight down until it finds a blank cell. The `Find` and `Copy` methods are not used at all, just a simple assignment statement.

```
Sub CopyBlastedData()
    Dim copiedBlastedWS As Worksheet
    Dim copiedBlastedData As Range

    Dim blastedData As Range
    Set blastedData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Full History File").Range("A1")
    Do While Not IsEmpty(blastedData)
        If blastedData.Value = "BLAST DRIVER ON" Then
            '--- create a new sheet
            Set copiedBlastedWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            Set copiedBlastedData = copiedBlastedWS.Range("A1")
            copiedBlastedData.Value = blastedData.Value
        Else
            copiedBlastedData.Value = blastedData.Value
        End If
        Set copiedBlastedData = copiedBlastedData.Offset(1, 0)
        Set blastedData = blastedData.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```